# Specific example in which is not enough to homogenize all the generators to get a generators for $I^*$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Given an ideal $I\subset \mathbb{k}[x,y,z]$, let $I^* \subset \mathbb{k}[x,y,z,w] $ be the ideal **generated** by $\{ F^* : F \in I \}$ where $F^*$ denotes the homogenization of the polynomial $F$.

I want to prove that if $I=(y-x^2,z-x^3)$ then $I^* \ne ((y-x^2)^*,(z-x^3)^*)$ by proving that $zw-xy \in I^*$ and $zw-xy \notin  ((y-x^2)^*,(z-x^3)^*)$.

I proved that $zw-xy \in I^*$ this is easy because $x(x^2-y)-(x^3-z)=z-xy \in I$ therefore its homogenization belongs to $I^*$.

I'm having problems with the second part. I'll rewrite this latter ideal by $(yw-x^2,zw^2-x^3)$.

Please tell me some technique to prove that an element does not belong to an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see that we don't have  $zw-xy \in  ((yw-x^2),(zw^2-x^3))$.

If that containment were true we would have $zw-xy =f\cdot( yw-x^2) +g\cdot (zw^2-x^3)$ for some polynomials $f,g\in k[x,y,z,w]$.
Taking the degree two homogeneous component in both sides of this equality  (that's the trick !) we get the relation $$zw-xy = f_0 \cdot ( yw-x^2)\in   k[x,y,z,w]     \quad (\bigstar)        $$ where $f_0\in k$ is the constant term of the polynomial $f$.
But the displayed equality $(\bigstar)$ of polynomials  is clearly impossible for any choice of the *constant* $f_0\in k$, thus proving that we cannot have $zw-xy \in  ((yw-x^2),(zw^2-x^3))$ .